# ngClass is not updated successfully in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have created a directive, that creates a popup with a ul element, but ng-class = isVisible is not returning the correct value. It works, if I only have one use of the directive at my page, but when multiple, it does not work.

My problem is, that ngClass is not updated when using this scope function.

```
function _isElementVisible(el, parent) {
var eap,
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    docEl = parent,
    vWidth = docEl.clientWidth,
    vHeight = docEl.clientHeight,
    efp = function (x, y) { return document.elementFromPoint(x, y) },
    contains = "contains" in el ? "contains" : "compareDocumentPosition",
    has = contains == "contains" ? 1 : 0x14;

// Return false if it's not in the viewport
if (rect.right < 0 || rect.bottom < 0
    || rect.left > vWidth || rect.top > vHeight)
    return false;

// Return true if any of its four corners are visible
return (
    (eap = efp(rect.left, rect.top)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
    || (eap = efp(rect.right, rect.top)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
    || (eap = efp(rect.right, rect.bottom)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
    || (eap = efp(rect.left, rect.bottom)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
    );
}

scope.isVisible = function (index) {
if (!scope.active)
    return false;

return _isElementVisible(jqElm.find('.modal li')[index], jqElm.find('.modal')[0]);
}

<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'visible': isVisible($index)}"></li>
```

Comment: I think your problem is in [scope isolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive). But it hard to tell while you not include directive definition in your question.

Comment: Can you add a plunkr to test and play with it?

Comment: The problem is that rect.left was always bigger then vWidth. I commented out this if - not a solution, but it works for now.